# Scala futures and JMM

Tags: scala, concurrency, jvm, thread-safety, future

I have a question about JMM and Scala futures.

In the following code, I have non-immutable **Data** class. I create an instance of it inside one thread(inside Future apply body), and then subscribe on completion event.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Hello extends App {
  Future {
    new Data(1, "2")
  }.foreach { d =>
    println(d)
  }
  Thread.sleep(100000)
}

class Data(var someInt: Int, var someString: String)
```

Can we guarantee that:

1. **foreach** body called from the same thread, where a Data instance was created?
2. If not, can we guarantee that actions inside the *Future.apply* **happens-before**(in terms of JMM) actions inside **foreach** body?

Comment: Does the Scala specification state that the JMM applies to Scala programs?

Comment: Holger, JMM is applied to any app, which runs on the JVM

Comment: Nope, the JMM is part of the Java *Language* Specification. The JVM has to conform to its own specification, and its fair to assume that, given a properly compiled Java application, its execution on the JVM will conform to the JMM. But this doesn’t say anything about an arbitrary programming language having different, unknown language constructs and even for similar constructs, when we don’t know the resulting byte code. Actually, your question is an example of that. Only Scala’s specification can answer it. And the first thing it has to specify, is whether the JMM applies to it (and how).

Answer (score 1):

Completion `happens-before` callback execution.

Disclaimer: I am the main contributor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a sort-of similar question, and what I found is -

1) in the doc Intellij so conveniently pulled up for me it says

> Asynchronously processes the value in the future once the value becomes available...

2) on https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html it says

> The result becomes available once the future completes.

Basically, it does not anywhere I can find say explicitly that there is a memory barrier. I *suspect*, however, that it is a safe assumption that there is. Otherwise the language would simply not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. **No**.

You can get a good idea of this by looking through the source code for `Promise`/`DefaultPromise`/`Future`, which schedules the callback for `foreach` on the execution context/adds it to the listeners without any special logic requiring it to run on the original thread...

But you can also verify it experimentally, by trying to set up an execution context and threads such that something else will already be queued for execution when the `Future` in which `Data` was created completes.

```
implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))

Future {
  new Data(1, "2")
  println("Data created on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
  Thread.sleep(100)
}.foreach { _ =>
  println("Data completed on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
}

Future { // occupies second thread
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}

Future { // queue for execution while first future is still executing
  Thread.sleep(2000)
}
```

My output:

> Data created on: pool-$n-thread-1
>
> Data completed on: pool-$n-thread-2

2.

Less confident here than I'd like to be, but I'll give it a shot:

**Yes.**

`DefaultPromise`, the construct underlying `Future`, is wrapping an atomic reference, which behaves like a volatile variable. Since the write-to for updating the result must happen prior to the read-from which passes the result to the listener so it can run the callback, JMM volatile variable rules turn this into a `happens-before` relationship.

Answer (score -1):

1. I don't think there are any guarantees that foreach is called from the same thread
2. foreach will not be called until the future completes succesfully. onComplete is a more idiomatic way of providing a callback to process the result of a Future.

Comment: You missed the point in the second question. I know that foreach will be called when future will be completed. My question was about relationships between those 2 actions in terms of JMM